# How can display a Digital Elevation Model (DEM) (.raw) using Python?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, rawimage

I want to display a DEM file (.raw) using Python, but there may be something wrong with the result.

Below is my code:

```
img1 = open('DEM.raw', 'rb')
rows = 4096
cols = 4096

f1 = np.fromfile(img1, dtype = np.uint8, count = rows * cols)
image1 = f1.reshape((rows, cols)) #notice row, column format
img1.close()

image1 = cv2.resize(image1, (image1.shape[1]//4, image1.shape[0]//4))
cv2.imshow('', image1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And I got this result:
[display result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr3rn.jpg)

The original DEM file is placed here: [DEM.raw](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QC8igmL2MadnSWI0NFzziouwgQlkITN2)

Comment: Aren't DEMs usually 16-bit integers?

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USGS_DEM, it says `The elevations are contiguous; breaks or other discontinuities are expressed using "void" elevations of value -32767. Each elevation is described as a six-character readable integer occupying a fixed location in a block.` So I don't think you should be specifying it as uint8

Comment: @fmw42 I agree with both your thoughts, Fred, yet the filesize does correspond to 4096x4096 of 8-bit data, rather than the 16-bit or ASCII formats you sensibly suggest. Mmmm... OP needs to check his sources, I think.

Comment: I figured out something, thank you @Mark Setchell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code, that's what's in your file. You can convert it to a JPEG or PNG with **ImageMagick** at the command line like this:

```
magick -size 4096x4096 -depth 8 GRAY:DEM.raw result.jpg
```

And you'll get pretty much the same:

[image]

The problem is elsewhere.

Taking the hint from Fred (@fmw42) and playing around, oops I mean *"experimenting carefully and scientifically"*, I can get a more likely looking result if I treat your image as 4096x2048 pixels with 16 bpp and MSB first endianness:

```
magick -size 4096x2048 -depth 16 -endian MSB gray:DEM.raw  -normalize result.jpg
```

[image]